# Inherit from arbitrary class in c++?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to design a class that will inherit from any one of a group of base classes? I would like to be able to write something like:

```cpp
class Derived : public ArbitraryBase {
    public:
        Derived () : ArbitraryBase () {}

    ...
};
```

where `ArbitraryBase` can be some base class determined at compile time. I have a group of base classes that I would like to derive identical classes from. Is there a way to avoid writing an individual derived class for each of the base classes?

Comment: "_where `ArbitraryBase` can be some base class determined at compile time._" How is it determined? Possible solutions might depend on that.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure exactly how it would work. I would need to specify which base class to inherit from when the derived class is constructed somehow.

Comment: One cannot construct derived class, before constructing the instance of base class. Base class instances are always constructed before derived class instances.

Answer (score 9):

If it is truly determined at compile time, you can make your derived class a template:

```
template<class T>
class Derived : public T {
    public:
        Derived() {}

    ...
};
```

You can later create instantiate this class by providing the base type:

```
int main() {
    Derived< ??? > my_object;

    ...
}
```

Where `???` is some compile time way of getting your derived type.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this via a template.  Using

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public T
{
public:
    Derived() : T() {}
    // or just use if actually need to provide a default constructor
    Derived() = default;
};
```

gives you a class that inherits from `T` and calls `T`'s default constructor.  You would create a concrete class with it like

```
Derived<Base1> d;
```

and now `d` is a `Derived` that inherits from `Base1`.

If you need to inherit from an arbitrary number of bases then you can use a variadic template like

```
template<typename... Bases>
class Derived : public Bases...
{
public:
    Dervied() : Bases()... {}
    // or just use if actually need to provide a default constructor
    Derived() = default;
};
```

and it would be used like

```
Derived<Base1, Base2, ..., BaseN> d;
```

Comment: What happens if you don't write `using T::T;`?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov Then it doesn't inherit from the bases(s).  I'm going to remove it though since the OP updated their code with `Derived` having it's own constructor.